# How to pass entity in saveWithBlock to completion block

Tags: ios, iphone, magicalrecord

I do know that `MagicalRecord` will execute `saveWithBlock` on backend thread and execute `completion` on main thread, but just get confused about how to pass entity in saveWithBlock to completion block, specifically:

```
Event *wantToCreateEvent = nil;
Event *wantToUpdateEvent = toBeUpdatedEvent;

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    wantToCreateEvent = [Event MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];

    Event *localContextEvent = [wantToUpdateEvent MR_inContext:localContext];
    localContextEvent.attri = @"newValue"
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    // Can I use wantToCreateEvent directly here?

    // Is wantToUpdateEvent updated here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Entity Creation you can use 2 functions of Megical Record

```
+ (id) MR_createEntityInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (id) MR_createEntity;
```

Note: For Saving the Entities You just have to Save the Context in which these entities are created

**Save In Background**

```
+ (void) saveWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block;
+ (void) saveWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block completion:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completion;
```

**Save in Main Thread**

```
+ (void) saveWithBlockAndWait:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block;
```

For More Understanding about CoreData With MegicalRecord I would recommend you to go through this tutorial

[Understanding CoreData With Magical Record](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-core-data-fetching-with-magical-record--mobile-13680)

Answer (score 0):

Use the __block storage type modifier on your variables if you need them to be modified from within a block.

```
__block Event *wantToCreateEvent = nil;
__block Event *wantToUpdateEvent = toBeUpdatedEvent;
```

According to Apple's documentation found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW3):

> Use __block Variables to Share Storage
>
> If you need to be able to change the value of a captured variable from within a block, you can use the __block storage type modifier on the original variable declaration. This means that the variable lives in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the original variable and any blocks declared within that scope.